# How to secure samba file server to access from windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I tried setting up the samba server with multiple configurations but i could not success on setting up a secure samba server.I want to setup a common share folder for our project and obviously it need to be access controlled for 20 users.I tried setting this up by integrating access with ubuntu user accounts but whenever i try to access the folder by default the default company domain is coming up in windows 7 and i'm not able to remove the domain when the credentials are prompted.

If not unique credentials for 20 users at east i should be able to authenticate the access with one username and password. Given that the nature of project artifacts this cannot be disclosed to anyone who just type in my server IP.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide in this situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, in your policy editor:

```
Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security 
Settings->Local Policies->Security Options
```

Find the policy:

```
Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)
```

If this is `enabled`, **change it to** `Disabled`. Be sure and restart your machine for the change to take effect! (Pressing the "Apply" button in the Policy Editor after the change is made is **not sufficient...**)

Once I did this, I was able to access my Samba share. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help on this.If you don't mind, could you please share me your smb.conf file? This would really help me to cross check and make sure that the configurations are right.

Comment: sure - here is a link [**smb.conf**](http://www.rlfpllc.com/dl/srv/smb.conf) Note: don't use the `config` share, that is an admin share that provides root access to server management, etc.. let me know if you have problems with the link. I'll move it to another box.

Comment: Thanks,I tried this on my personal machine and it worked.I shall try this in my project server tomorrow and verify it!